# Best practice for assets in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, assets

When would assets get loaded in Angular app? Will app wait for all assets to be loaded before starting to bootstrap, or those will be lazy loaded if they are not required on initial page.

I have a lot of PDFs that I put in assets folder and load them when required. Now, I am concern about the performance, and I was thinking to upload all PDFs to cloud and instead of loading them from assets I would load them from cloud. Would that make app initial load faster?

Answer (score 3):

Files in assets gets loaded as and when they are requested by the components.

They won't be bundled in to the output JS files produced by the Angular build process. So your bundle size will not be impacted by the number of files you have put in to the assets folder.

If you are concerned to make the app's initial load faster, make sure that your you are splitting your code in different bundles and the main bundle only contains the components required for initial page load.

You can implement lazy loaded modules to split your application code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  So I can put as much PDFs in assets and that won't affect the performance (app won't wait for all of it to load before starting to bootstrap)? Also, tnx for suggesting the lazy loaded modules, I am already doing that.

Comment: yes, as these PDFs won't be bundled in your JS, it wont cause performance issues due to PDFs. Which components references those PDFs and they are patrt of which module?